# How to install Spatialite-GIS on Windows?

Tags: installation, spatialite, windows

I was wondering if there is a way to install Spatialite-gis on a Windows & machine?  I have found may posts and links about this, but I have yet to find an installer for spatialite-gis.  This Google Group post links to different sites, but there are not installers available, am I missing something?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/5qHN1oUq5oQ

This is the direct link from GAIA to spatialite-gis, but there are no installers.
https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gis/index

This is a link to other downloads, including spatialite-gui, but nothing for spatialite-gis
http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/

Answer (score 2):

From the [Gaia GIS homepage](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html):

```
Obsolete / Discontinued software [no longer maintained]
...
spatialite-gis  sources     a minimalistic GIS tool built on the top
                            of SpatiaLite and RasterLite
```

They still offer the sources, but no binaries (as for the gui). So you have to compile it yourself from the sources. The homepage gives some details for various platforms.

Or switch to QGIS, which has much more features. Might be a reason why Gaia does not maintain its old project.

Comment: I have switched, but I wanted a lite weight GUI for non technical GIS users. QGIS can be a bit too much for someone who is not a GIS user, but needs to look at data

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link of SpatiaLite for windows:

https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.3.1/spatialite-gis-win-x86-1.0-ALPHA-1.zip

[image: capture de la page de ce lien]